# Angular2 linq style property accessor

Tags: javascript, linq, angular, model

Often, we are presented with an array (IEnumerable) property that specific values need to be extracted.  in c# we can do something similar to:

```
public AssetModel PromoImage {
        get
        {
            return Assets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AssetTypeCd == "promoimage");
        }
        private set { }
    }
```

Is there a way to easily to this within Angular 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com) provides similar functionality to LINQ for JavaScript programs (and then some), though not deferred execution -- LINQ queries are deferred until they are enumerated, while lodash (usually) performs the query immediately and returns an array/object of results.  (Though in this case LINQ wouldn't even defer it since `FirstOrDefault` returns a scalar and not a queryable/enumerable.)

In your case, you would do something like this:

```
let obj = {
    get promoImage() {
        return _.find(assets, a => a.assetTypeCd === 'promoimage');
    },

    // ...
};
```

Then accessing `obj.promoImage` will execute the function to obtain the attribute's value.

(Here I assume this is where we are creating the new object, and `assets` is the assets list in the lexical scope of the constructor function. You can change it to reference `this` if you are storing data on the object itself and not in constructor upvalues.)

---

Notes:

- Lodash does not depend on Angular at all.
- ES6 provides a [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method on the Array prototype, so this feature will be built-in to browsers once ES6 is adopted.  Sadly, IE is (as usual) the outlier without any support for it.  However, Lodash is still a very useful library to have in your toolkit, and note that Lodash's `find()` works on objects too, not just arrays.